# I have a question about women haircut

Tags: husband-wife, hair

Asalam aleikom,

I am married. And actually I am so attracted with short hair (pixie cut). And my wife she doesn’t like short hair (pixie cut) at all. I have asked her so many times she did cut a few time but now she won’t do it any more. And I am not happy when my wife has long hair. We fight everyday about this haircut subject she does not accept cutting her hair short (pixie cut). But there is a rule in Islam I think that a women should obey her husband. And I don’t think expecting short hair  from wife is a sin or a bad thing. I told her so many times that if she don’t want to have short hair anymore I will leave her. Because I am not attracted to long hair women. And also my wife is 5 months pregnant. Can anyone help me what to do ? Should she listen to me that I am her husband or I have no rights on her to ask such a thing?

Comment: Women are allowed to cut their hair to please the husband, but they should avoid having a haircut similar to men.

Comment: What about pixie cut?? Can you explain that ? And there is a Hadith also about the prophet wives that they had their hair until ears. Is that correct Hadith or no ?

Comment: It is rather too short for being allowed. Further it could be regarded as a haircut that make her look like a man or like non-Muslim or disrespectful women. The hadith you are referring to is speaking about the length from the hair of the middle of the head till the end of the ears this is rather the length of 1- 2 hands not trimmed for 1bor 2 cm.

Comment: So it’s not allowed for women to cut their hair short like pixie ? And what if a her husband wants it so much. Like he is so attracted to that pixie hair. And when she have long hair I am not happy even I don’t wanna go near to her. In this case what should I do? Cuz I can’t be with her if she have long hair.